# filter array string using back_inserter from input chars at any place

Tags: c++

I have a textbox & a list of strings (array). I am filtering the list using `std::back_inserter`:

```
std::vector<string> upprCase;
....
std::remove_copy_if(
    upprCase.begin(), 
    upprCase.end(), 
    std::back_inserter(filteredList), 
    std::not1(filter(str2)));
```

Using this, I am able to filter initial chars of the string, but how to filter string with chars at any place?

For example, if `upprCase` is `{abc,bcd,cde}` and `str2=bc` (coming from textbox), I want `filteredlist{abc,bcd}`

Answer (score 0):

```
// copies only the items where predicate returns 'false' ... 
std::remove_copy_if(
    upprCase.begin(),
    upprCase.end(),
    std::back_inserter(filteredList),
    [&](const std::string &s){ return (s.find(str2) == std::string::npos); }
);
```

Or:

```
// copies only the items where predicate returns 'true' ... 
std::copy_if(
    upprCase.begin(),
    upprCase.end(),
    std::back_inserter(filteredList),
    [&](const std::string &s){ return (s.find(str2) != std::string::npos); }
);
```